# Node and MySQL connection to database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need t o provide the MySQL connection for modules, so I provide the code like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql')
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '149.xxx.xx.x',
    user: 'User',
    password: 'Password',
    database: 'DataBase',
    port: 1443, 
});

connection.connect(
    function(error) {
        console.log(error.code); // 'ECONNREFUSED'
        console.log(error.fatal); // true
        console.log(error.sql); 
        console.log(error.sqlMessage);     
}
);
```

and after some time (about 1-2 minutes) I received an error from those console.logs:

```
ECONNRESET
true
undefined
undefined
```

I think maybe it's the timeout because of my "nonactivity", but when I'm trying to do the query the errors are the same.

Have any idea what is wrong? I checked it from DataGrip and the data are correct.

Comment: How are you doing the query? Can you show the code for that?

Comment: Are you sure it's a MySQL server? Port 1443 is the default port for MS SQL Server.

Comment: @mscdex I will ask tomorrow, but backend developer told me about mysql. For sure I will check asap this mssql for node library.

Comment: @mscdex I checked and it must be a MS SQL Server.

I am using the mssql library, but now I have error like:

name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xx.x:1433 in 15000ms',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT' }

Comment: My mistake, I believe it's actually 1433 for MS SQL Server. I believe it may be a typo though and still is an MS SQL Server instance (3306 is the default MySQL port number).

Comment: @mscdex Below I paste the new code and the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found one small bug here. The database is **MS SQL Server (microsoft)**. I'm trying now using the library called `mssql` to connect to that database, provide some code:

```
var config = {
    server: "149.xxx.xx.x",
    database: "Database",
    user: "User",
    password: "Password",
    connectionTimeout: 300000,
    requestTimeout: 300000,
    pool: {
        idleTimeoutMillis: 300000,
        max: 100
    }
};

function getEmp() {
    var connection = new sql.Connection(config);
    var req = new sql.Request(connection);

    connection.connect(function (error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
        req.query('Procedure', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
            }
            connection.close();
        });
    });
}

getEmp();
```

and I receive the error:

```
{ ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 149.xxx.xx.x:1433 - connect ETIMEDOUT 149.xxx.xx.x:1433
at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/phuzarski/Learning/NodeJS/srv-express/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:353:25)
at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Connection.socketError (/Users/phuzarski/Learning/NodeJS/srv-express/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:791:12)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/phuzarski/Learning/NodeJS/srv-express/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:33:15)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)


 name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Failed to connect to 149.xxx.xx.x:1433 - connect ETIMEDOUT 149.xxx.xx.x:1433',
  code: 'ESOCKET' }
```

For sure the data are correct- DataGrip is connecting fine here.

I found at google the similar problem, the problem was Disabled TCP/IP. I checked this one and it's Enabled with this port 1443.